# Enable Sound button in Notification Channel

Tags: android, notifications, mi

In **MI Note 5 Pro** which has latest **MI UI 10.0 with Oreo**, so when I try to send **push notification** by default **sound** is disable, so i am not able to **enable sound** programmatically when I am creating a **channel** for that.

In other Oreo devices notification sound is coming but in MI custom Oreo OS Sound is by default disable

*Let me show my code for notification* :

```
    var intent = Intent(mContext, HomeActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true)
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    var uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

    var mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(mFirstContactName + " : " + mListChatWindow[0].message)
            .setPriority(if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH else Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(uri)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 100, 1000, 300))
            .setAutoCancel(true)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        var channel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        channel.description = "NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTION"
        channel.lightColor = Color.LTGRAY
        channel.enableVibration(true)
        channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC

        val attributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION).build()
        channel.setSound(uri, attributes)
        var notificationManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext)
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_CHAT_ID, mBuilder.build())
```

I am also set **channel.setSound(uri, attributes)** in cannel but sound not coming

Here is the screenshot of Notification channel see there sound icon is disabled, how to enable?

Plz help

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a MIUI 10 issue, facing similar issue on Pocofone.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @NishanthSreedhara Not right now! If you found any answer plz share here.

Comment: Same here :(... There must be a trick, because WhatsApp, Facebook and other app are able to do this. We are missing something...

Comment: Sure, we need to find this

Comment: I think, MiUI have a white listed apps to enable sound notifications by default

Comment: So any solution till now? I have slimier issue on flutter app for MIUI device to receive default sound.

Comment: Still facing this problem for `Xiaomi` and `nexus6p`  devices. Any solution from anyone?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem in MIUI Global 10.1 with oreo but it was only while using custom sound and not like yours, default sound. Any way let me explain how I solve it and hope it may solve yours.

First thing to consider is where the registration of notification channel is executed. It must be executed in Application.onCreate so that the channel is created even before the notification arrives. I was doing it in onMessageReceived.

Second as I said it was working for default notification sound and not for custom one, I inserted below code while creating notification channel and it worked.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND); // This line did the magic for me.

        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound_notification_plucky);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();

        CharSequence name = "MyChild";
        String description = "All MyChild messages";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(description);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing same issue and still didn't get satisfying answer, but till that time we can workaround it like so:

```
final Uri NOTIFICATION_SOUND = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, NOTIFICATION_SOUND).play();
```

You need to call this **after**:

```
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

This way you will always get sound playing even if "allow sound" was turned off for your App, and the sound played will be from the system not media (expected behavior from the notifications).

And to avoid having two sounds playing at once (for the devices that don't have this issue), you can turn the sounds off like so:

1- For the Builder:

```
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
    .set.....
    .set.....
    .setSound(null);
```

2- For the channel:

```
channel.setSound(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

This line of code is worked for me it enables all notification settings.